# Why can not I log in Ubuntu?

Tags: system

After a failed installation cuda, I entered the password correctly, but this does not lead to anything. What should I do?

Console screenshot:

[image: Console Screenshot]

Reset ubuntu :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Used.. chown mrrobot:mrrobor .Xauthority ..but can not log in.

Comment: @Neil you are missing a ~/ in there ;) `rm ~/.Xauthority`

Comment: @Rinzwind whats the point of `~/` when your in the home directory ?

Comment: Absolute paths are safer than relative paths.  You assume he is in the home. He could be in another users home and then "~/.Xauthority" and .Xauthority" are both valid but done on different files (not that is actually a problem though, the file gets recreated anyways but just a bit more safer)

Comment: @Rinzwind I did it but nothing changed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, and push (alt+Ctrl+f6), and type in yours users name and password, and then type this in the tty:

```
dconf reset /etc/compiz
unity --replace --reset-icon & disown
```

and it might work.

Comment: "could" and "might." Two words that are definite no-nos in an answer. Put it as a comment.

Comment: unknown command '-f'

Comment: @MaxZueff This is just some crap as an answer.